# Rooted trees with labelled leaves

Tags: forest, trees

I am trying to draw something like this

[image]

using the forest package:

1. how do I draw a tree with circles at every node in a way that I can still label the leaves?
2. is there a way to add dots between branches as in the pic? And curly brackets?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `forest` isn't really designed to draw trees that look like this (i.e., with varying growth directions).  See [Forest: different growing directions for branches on the same level](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/151042) for some discussion. The other parts of your question are easily answerable however.

Comment: The `tikz` graphs library might be more appropriate for this type of tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many of these you have, this solution may do what you want. Adjusting the position of the brace and its label is a bit of trial and error. I don't know if there's a way to make this more automatic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\forestset{solid nodes/.style={for tree={circle,draw,inner sep=1,fill=black}},
            dir/.style={for tree={grow=#1}},
            leaf/.style={label=$#1$},
            mytree/.style={solid nodes, for tree={grow=north,s sep=1cm}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}mytree
[[
    [,dir=north east
        [,leaf=\mu,name=X] [,leaf=\mu,name=Y] [,leaf=S_2]
    ]
    [,dir=north west     
         [,dir=north east
            [,leaf=\mu_2] [,leaf=\mu_1] 
         ]
         [,leaf=S_1]
    ]
]]
\draw[dotted] (Y) -- (X);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt}] ($(Y)+(0,.35)$) -- node [pos=0.8,above=2.5ex] {$e$} ($(X)+(0,.35)$)  ;
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]